# Learning languages alone

Tags: self-learning

I am trying to learn languages like French, German, Italian and others with the help of dictionaries and books from the English school that I went in the past. I think I have books starting from the level of a junior up to proficiency. What I do is this: I try to  learn whatever is in those books in the language I am aiming. For example, if it is German, I try to take the first page of the book and try to translate with the help of the dictionary to German. After I finish with the first page I move to the next and after that to the next and so on.

Will my way of learning languages have good results with or without giving exams to get a degree or certificate in those languages?

Comment: Hi there and welcome the Language Learning SE! In general questions should be written in a way such that there's is only one question, so you may want to edit your current question. If you'd like some more guidance on the SE format and the specifics of this site, check out the [tour](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/tour) or [help center](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @gabbo1092, thank you.

Comment: None of what you describe is a good language learning method. Also, do you realize you have many English mistakes?

Comment: @Lambie, why are they not a good language learning method?Which are my English mistakes? Could you give me some examples of them?

Comment: You keep saying learn what is in the books which means nothing in language learning. Can you actually have a conversation?

Comment: For a better exercise, I recommend *reading* about a topic in the language you are learning. For example, if you are learning German, and if you like history or are interested in that topic, then you would do well to *read* lots of books, articles, etc. (in German) about that topic. With this exercise, you do not need to translate to German, and when you encounter new German words, you will probably already have an intuitive sense for what they mean, since you are familiar with the topic (e.g. history). And since you are interested in the topic, you will be motivated to continue reading.

Comment: Good way to learn language is whatever works for you and, importantly, can be sustained in a long run. Having said that, you might do better progress (at least initially) by taking a course or using some self-study books (like those from *Teach yourself* or *Assimil* series.) This could help you to focus on what is really essential and general, rather than wasting time on idiosyncrasies of every language.